# Software with foldable/expandable view of multiple txt/md files

Tags: software-recommendation, markdown

I have many todo files in markdown format scattered on my directories tree. I like to keep it this way because my todo files stay in each project folder. But I also like to get a global overview of what to do in all my projects, so I'm using for now a small script that read a list of paths to those files, concatenate the files into a single file. I'm using geany for opening this file. If I want to modify anything, I need to open the original file, save it and reapply my script.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a software/geany plugin/atom plugin that would be able to open those multiple files in the same view. 
Ideally, I would like to be able to:

- fold/expand files one by one
- save any modification in the view directly on the original .md file
- syntax coloration, though I could do without
- open source

Yet, I haven't found something closer to that than my concatenation. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could create a plain-text list of your todo files, then use right-click "Open selected file" in Geany to open just that file in a separate tab.

Comment: That's exaclty what I'm doing right now. The problem is that I can't fold/expand, and I need to open the files separately, and rerun my script

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [VNote](https://github.com/tamlok/vnote) will suite your needs.

See official screenshot below:

[image: VNote]

You can [download it](https://github.com/tamlok/vnote/releases) and use as AppImage:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/tamlok/vnote/releases/download/v2.4/VNote-2.4-x86_64.AppImage
chmod +x VNote-2.4-x86_64.AppImage
./VNote-2.4-x86_64.AppImage
```

Comment: Seem a interesting software!  I haven't found the way to open a note while keeping its original location on the disk... and neither how to have multiple/all my notes open in a raw

Comment: You can switch between raw and preview by pressing `<Ctrl+T>`. Not sure about notes location.

Comment: sorry not "in a raw", but "in a row"

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion would be [Zim](https://zim-wiki.org/), which you will find in Ubuntu Software. It also works based on text notes in markup language. It shows you a tree of your notes to the left, and allows to link between notes.

While you could work like you do now, it features a Todo plugin that takes a different approach. You can insert your todo's in any note using a checkbox. The plugin can then collect all these todo's from the different pages and show them in a list, ordered by due date and priorities.

Excellent software from a developer who clearly uses his software intensively himself.